# Parsing a JSON file using json library/requests

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to parse a JSON file and it is giving me a bit of trouble. I have parsed JSON before but have never had this problem.

The site is protected by cloudflare which I bypassed using the python module for it. The content that is returned is in json. Here is what it looks like:

```
stock{

{'sizes': 
   {
   'B79759_550': {'size': '5', 'stock': 68}, 
   'B79759_590': {'size': '7', 'stock': 20}, 
   'B79759_600': {'size': '7.5', 'stock': 5}, 
   'B79759_610': {'size': '8', 'stock': 681}, 
   'B79759_620': {'size': '8.5', 'stock': 807}, 
   'B79759_630': {'size': '9', 'stock': 775}, 
   'B79759_640': {'size': '9.5', 'stock': 978}, 
   'B79759_650': {'size': '10', 'stock': 1097}, 
   'B79759_660': {'size': '10.5', 'stock': 814}, 
   'B79759_670': {'size': '11', 'stock': 779}, 
   'B79759_680': {'size': '11.5', 'stock': 581}, 
   'B79759_690': {'size': '12', 'stock': 643}, 
   'B79759_700': {'size': '12.5', 'stock': 5}, 
   'B79759_710': {'size': '13', 'stock': 620}, 
   'B79759_730': {'size': '14', 'stock': 19}
   },
   'total_stock': 7892
}
}
```

So far I have managed to get to the skus (The numbers that start with B79759) using this code:

```
resp = scraper.post(link,data=payload,headers=headers).json()
stock = resp["stock"]
sizes = stock["sizes"]
for size in sizes:
    print(size)
```

Now this only gives me the SKU's ("B79759_550,B79759_590,B79759_600 etc)
I want to be able to get the size and the stock numbers as well. I tried to do:

```
resp = scraper.post(link,data=payload,headers=headers).json()
stock = resp["stock"]
sizes = stock["size"]
stock = sizes["stock"]
actual_size = sizes["size"]
print(stock)
```

Both of these resulted in key errors for ["size"]. I have never had this problem before and don't know what I'm doing wrong exactly.

Comment: When your looping through the SKUs, that is when you can access size and stock.

Comment: You just need one more level of indexing; `sizes` is a `dict` just like `resp` and `stock`; your iterator is just iterating over the keys. `sizes[size]['size']` and `sizes[size]['stock']` will get the values in the innermost dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resp = scraper.post(link,data=payload,headers=headers).json()
stock = resp["stock"]
sizes = stock["sizes"]
for sku in sizes:
    print(sku)
    print(sizes[sku]["size"])
```

Your first code snippet is getting close, the size (I changed it to sku so it's easier to parse the JSON in my head) that's being printed is each key which you'll need to find each object and get the size.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting the JSON response that you would get by using scraper:

```
response = {
    "stock": {
        "sizes": {
            "B79759_550": {
                "size": "5",
                "stock": 68
            },
            "B79759_590": {
                "size": "7",
                "stock": 20
            },
            "B79759_600": {
                "size": "7.5",
                "stock": 5
            },
            "B79759_610": {
                "size": "8",
                "stock": 681
            },
            "B79759_620": {
                "size": "8.5",
                "stock": 807
            },
            "B79759_630": {
                "size": "9",
                "stock": 775
            },
            "B79759_640": {
                "size": "9.5",
                "stock": 978
            },
            "B79759_650": {
                "size": "10",
                "stock": 1097
            },
            "B79759_660": {
                "size": "10.5",
                "stock": 814
            },
            "B79759_670": {
                "size": "11",
                "stock": 779
            },
            "B79759_680": {
                "size": "11.5",
                "stock": 581
            },
            "B79759_690": {
                "size": "12",
                "stock": 643
            },
            "B79759_700": {
                "size": "12.5",
                "stock": 5
            },
            "B79759_710": {
                "size": "13",
                "stock": 620
            },
            "B79759_730": {
                "size": "14",
                "stock": 19
            }
        },
        "total_stock": 7892
    }
}
```

The following lines of code will return a list of all the sizes by using [list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
stock_details = response['stock']
stock_setails = stock_details['sizes'].values()
size = [size['size'] for size in stock_setails]
print(size)
```